# Two Glassfish Instances ( Cluster ) in 1 CPU with 10 cores

Tags: java, glassfish, cluster-computing

Will there be a performance improvement If I put a cluster of two glassfish instances in one machine ( 2 cpu with 10 cores ).

If there is a performance improvement, what way it would be ?

Comment: [Performance Rant](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: As opposed to what?  Also note that you need to relocate the ports of at least one of the two instances.  This can be done during installation with an appropriate command line argument.

Comment: what difference it makes if I create 2 instances in a single machine. I can increase the max connections limit, increase thread pools count, etc. I can do all these customisation on one instance right ? so my question is, is it better to keep one instance or multiple instances ?